# Redis ZRANGEBYLEX matching secondary indexes

Tags: redis

I have an index for each user which represents their current score.
I want to find all users with the same score.

Provided that the input is as follows, how can I retrieve only users 1 and 2?

```
ZADD users 0 1:10
ZADD users 0 2:10
ZADD users 0 3:5
```

I would expect to do something like mentioned in the [docs](https://redis.io/commands/zrangebyscore) but I cannot use the key as my index since it is too large (for the post I changed to 1,2,3 so it is not an issue), which is why I set it to 0.

I thought the command could be something like `ZRANGEBYLEX users [0:10 (:10` but that returns all 3.

```
1) "1:10"
2) "2:10"
3) "3:5"
```

Comment: The ZADD command syntax is `ZADD key score member`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to come up with a solution for this problem, which can further refine as:

> Retrieve all users with a given score or retrieve a single score for a single user.

What I determined was that using the namespace `users` is not a sufficient descriptor for both the score and user id. When using 2 different keys, it is clearly possible to get either a range or a single value. The downside is twice the writes I had hoped, but that is overall not a lot of overhead for me and the only way I found to properly retrieve both score and user.

```
ZADD score:users 0 10:1
ZADD score:users 0 10:2
ZADD score:users 0 5:3

ZADD users:score 0 1:10
ZADD users:score 0 2:10
ZADD users:score 0 3:5

ZRANGEBYLEX users:score [1: [1:\xff # "1:10" 
ZRANGEBYLEX score:users [10: [10:\xff # "10:1" "10:2"
```